# Vue: get url params

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

According to information from the documentation. I can get the parameters from the url and pass them to the component as a parameter.
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#function-mode

I try it:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter);

var router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        { path: '/', component: App, props: (route) => ({ query: route.query.q }) }
      ]
})

new Vue({
    router,
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
})
```

App.vue:

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'app',
    data () {
      return {

      }
    },
    mounted: function() {
      console.log(this.query)
    },
  }
</script>
```

In console:

> undefined

How correctly to receive parameters from url?

Answer (score 2):

When you use `vue-router`, `$route` object is attached to every component you create. In this `$route` component, you have a `query` object. It's in this query object that you will find your parameters.

So instead of writing `console.log(this.query)`, you should write `console.log(this.$route.query)`, you'll get an object containing all the parameters passed in the URL.

This is available by default, so there's no need to write `props: (route) => ({ query: route.query.q })`, you can just write : `{ path: '/', component: App }`